# Google Service Account by REST

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Hi to all and sorry for my English!

I'm new to Google-API and I need use Google Service Account to access Google-API on my php server.
I can't use `client-php-google-api`, so I'd like call google-api by REST.

Do I need a refresh token? If Yes, how can I get a refresh token for service account?

Comment: which api endpoints you want to call on google services? do they involve user's personal data?

Comment: I need verify Android subscription/purchase status of my Android App users

Answer (score 1):

You will require a service account and access token (No need for refresh token in this scenario). To get an access token, you will require JWT. JWT token has an expiry of maximum 1 hour and you will need to re-issue a new JWT after its expiry. Please refer to following guide on getting JWT/Access Token and then making API calls:

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)